# How to get the value of r when I have the value of r^² ( 1000 = r^2)?

Tags: exponentiation

I do not remember this from school anymore and I now I have to use the logarithm but the problem is that I do not know the base. I want to know the value of r but I only have the value of r^2.

2² = 2*2 and the inverse is log2(4) but in my case how do not have the value of the base.
Thank you.

Comment: Take the square root.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't need the logarithm but a square root: $\sqrt{1000}$. However, presume for some reason you *have* to use logarithms somewhere(?!)

For positive $x$ it is true that $\sqrt{x}=x^{1/2}=a^{\frac12\log_ax}$ for *any* base $a\gt 0$ you choose. So, pick the base that is the easiest to work with. In this case, $1000=10^3$, i.e. $\log_{10}1000=3$ and so $a=10$ is a nice base to work with. Now it follows that $\sqrt{1000}=10^{3/2}$.

Comment: thank you. I was completly miles away.